# What are these spots with yellow halos on my cucumber leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, cucumbers

They've been growing for 3 months so I assume they're at the end of their lifespan- but I want to identify this. Is this a disease or just some sun beating down on it?

[image]

[image]

[image]